# Is every local ring the localization of some other ring?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

One way of constructing a local ring is to start with any commutative ring, and localize all the elements outside of some maximal ideal (i.e., adjoining inverses to all those elements). But I'm wondering: can every local ring be constructed in this way? Obviously, a local ring is the localization of itself at its unique maximal ideal, but is there always a non-local ring which localizes to our ring?

Edit: As noted in the comments, $R\times k$ works for any commutative ring $k$, so what about if we don't allow disconnected rings?

Comment: Sure; if $R$ is a local ring, then it's a localization of $R \times k$ for any other commutative ring $k$...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Why not adding this as an answer?

Comment: I was assuming the OP would add more conditions (e.g. connected).

Comment: Well, I just looked up the definition of a connected ring, and it seems that $R\times k$ is not connected...what about if we require the nonlocal ring to be connected?

Comment: Another trivial example - $R[x]/x^2$ localized at $x$ is just $R$. Excluding this example is a little less straightforward.

Comment: @Asvin The OP asks for the localization at a maximal ideal.